# MongoDB $elemMatch find mulitple elements

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to do a find on a collection for entries that match both 'number' and 'scheduledTimeLocal' on the data set below:

I am using elemMatch as per below:

```
db.collection.find({ arrivals: { $elemMatch: { 'number': 'KL 1451', 'movement.scheduledTimeLocal': { $regex: /2020-05-23/} } } })
```

But this doesn't seem to find the result - can this type of find actually be done? I'd rather not have to do the full search and then iterate through the results.

Many thanks

```
{
  "departures": [
    {
      "movement": {
        "airport": {
          "icao": "EHAM",
          "iata": "AMS",
          "name": "Amsterdam"
        },
        "scheduledTimeLocal": "2020-05-23 12:25+01:00",
        "scheduledTimeUtc": "2020-05-23 11:25Z",
        "quality": [
          "Basic"
        ]
      },
      "number": "KL 1446",
      "status": "CanceledUncertain",
      "codeshareStatus": "IsOperator",
      "isCargo": false,
      "aircraft": {
        "model": "Embraer 190"
      },
      "airline": {
        "name": "KLM"
      }
    },
    {
      "movement": {
        "airport": {
          "icao": "EGLL",
          "iata": "LHR",
          "name": "London"
        },
        "scheduledTimeLocal": "2020-05-23 14:50+01:00",
        "scheduledTimeUtc": "2020-05-23 13:50Z",
        "quality": [
          "Basic"
        ]
      },
      "number": "BA 1309",
      "status": "Unknown",
      "codeshareStatus": "IsOperator",
      "isCargo": false,
      "aircraft": {
        "model": "Airbus A319"
      },
      "airline": {
        "name": "British Airways"
      }
    }
  ],
  "arrivals": [
    {
      "movement": {
        "airport": {
          "icao": "LFPG",
          "iata": "CDG",
          "name": "Paris"
        },
        "scheduledTimeLocal": "2020-05-23 21:10+01:00",
        "scheduledTimeUtc": "2020-05-23 20:10Z",
        "quality": [
          "Basic"
        ]
      },
      "number": "AF 1472",
      "status": "Unknown",
      "codeshareStatus": "Unknown",
      "isCargo": false,
      "aircraft": {
        "model": "Embraer 170"
      },
      "airline": {
        "name": "Air France"
      }
    },
    {
      "movement": {
        "airport": {
          "icao": "EHAM",
          "iata": "AMS",
          "name": "Amsterdam"
        },
        "scheduledTimeLocal": "2020-05-23 22:15+01:00",
        "scheduledTimeUtc": "2020-05-23 21:15Z",
        "quality": [
          "Basic"
        ]
      },
      "number": "KL 1451",
      "status": "CanceledUncertain",
      "codeshareStatus": "IsOperator",
      "isCargo": false,
      "aircraft": {
        "model": "Boeing 737-700"
      },
      "airline": {
        "name": "KLM"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by But this doesn't seem to find the result, can you please explain more, as when I run this query it seems to return the doc

Comment: I am able to see all the documents, @PuneetSingh, is this happening with you? Basically filtering is not working.

Comment: When you search the documents it will show the complete documents, if by filtering means arrivals array elements

Comment: Hi - Sorry, yes it retrieves the whole docuement. Thanks I will try the $filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$filter` operator in aggregation, like below:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      arrivals: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$arrivals",
          as: "arrival",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$arrival.number",
                  "KL 1451"
                ]
              },
              {
                $regexMatch: {
                  input: "$$arrival.movement.scheduledTimeLocal",
                  regex: /2020-05-23/
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      departures: 1
    }
  }
])
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ecXc8aX134X87"),
  "departures" : [
    {
      "movement": {
        "airport": {
          "icao": "EHAM",
          "iata": "AMS",
          "name": "Amsterdam"
        },
        "scheduledTimeLocal": "2020-05-23 12:25+01:00",
        "scheduledTimeUtc": "2020-05-23 11:25Z",
        "quality": [
          "Basic"
        ]
      },
      "number": "KL 1446",
      "status": "CanceledUncertain",
      "codeshareStatus": "IsOperator",
      "isCargo": false,
      "aircraft": {
        "model": "Embraer 190"
      },
      "airline": {
        "name": "KLM"
      }
    },
    {
      "movement": {
        "airport": {
          "icao": "EGLL",
          "iata": "LHR",
          "name": "London"
        },
        "scheduledTimeLocal": "2020-05-23 14:50+01:00",
        "scheduledTimeUtc": "2020-05-23 13:50Z",
        "quality": [
          "Basic"
        ]
      },
      "number": "BA 1309",
      "status": "Unknown",
      "codeshareStatus": "IsOperator",
      "isCargo": false,
      "aircraft": {
        "model": "Airbus A319"
      },
      "airline": {
        "name": "British Airways"
      }
    }
  ],
  "arrivals" : [
    {
      "movement": {
        "airport": {
          "icao": "EHAM",
          "iata": "AMS",
          "name": "Amsterdam"
        },
        "scheduledTimeLocal": "2020-05-23 22:15+01:00",
        "scheduledTimeUtc": "2020-05-23 21:15Z",
        "quality": [
          "Basic"
        ]
      },
      "number": "KL 1451",
      "status": "CanceledUncertain",
      "codeshareStatus": "IsOperator",
      "isCargo": false,
      "aircraft": {
        "model": "Boeing 737-700"
      },
      "airline": {
        "name": "KLM"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your query is you're using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html#elemmatch-query) query operator but not [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html#elemmatch-projection) which is a projection operator.

Difference between both of these are :

```
.find({ filter }, { projection }) // Let's see on simple find query
```

If you use `$elemMatch` query operator in **filter** then docs with the entire array(all elements in the array) will be returned even if just one element/object in the array matches with the criteria.

But when `$elemMatch` projection operator is used in **projection** it would get you only the element/object from array that meets the criteria.

**Query :**

```
db.collection.find({}, { arrivals: { $elemMatch: { "number": "KL 1451", "movement.scheduledTimeLocal": { $regex: "2020-05-23" } } } })
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cb-jl6-HjoW)

**Note :**

1. `$elemMatch` is similar to positional `$` operator both of these will only return the first matching element even if there are multiple elements/objects in array that match with given criteria. If you've multiple matching elements & need all of the them to be returned in output array, then try aggregation operator [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html).
2. Also note that when using `$elemMatch` in projection if it doesn't find any matching element in array, then that field will be removed from the output document (In your case if no matching object is found then you don't see `arrivals` array in response for that particular document). But if you need an empty array then you need to lean towards using `$filter`. But I believe there is a reason for this as sometimes removing a field is much better than returning falsy value `[]` on that field.
3. If needed, you can use this `$elemMatch` in both filter & projection, for better performance & also to get only the docs where the criteria is met.